# Jenkins - How to execute a .SQL file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, jenkins, sqlcmd

I'm trying to execute a .SQL in my Pipeline. I'm using sqlcmd to launch it from a bat command. i.e. : `bat "sqlcmd -e -S \"(localdb)\\MyServer01\" -d \"MyDB01\" -i \"C:\\test.sql\" -U \"user123\" -P \"pass123\""`

---

In the file Test.sql : `select * from MyDB01.sys.user_token`

---

When I execute it directly on Command Prompt on my slave, it works, but when I build my Pipeline, it gives me this error : `Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'user123'..`

---

Can someone help me ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

SQLCMD does not support quotes in password. You need to write just:

```
... -P pass123
```

If your password contains special symbols, then you need to set env variable before executing SQLCMD (using special jenkins plugin that injects env variables):

```
SET SQLCMDPASSWORD= p@a$$w0rd
```